# ORACLE DECODE with multiple expressions or multiple decodes

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

I have the below data in an Oracle table which I'm trying to perform calculations based on TYPE & QT columns.

```
TYPE QT STATUS  CNT
---- -- ------  ---
E    A  YES     123
E    A  NO     2540
E    D  YES       2
E    D  NO      787
O    A  YES     884
O    A  NO     6957
O    D  YES      25
O    D  NO     1360
```

Looks like my expected output now is different.. like below :

```
TYPE    TOTAL   A   A&Y
----    -----   ----    -----
E+O     12678   10504   1007
E       3452     2663    123
```

My old oracle sql is below but the output is wrong when calculating the percentages:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT NVL(SUM(DECODE(A.QT,'A',A.CNT,'D',A.CNT)),0) AS "TOTAL",
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(A.QT,'A',A.CNT)),0) AS "A ALL",
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(A.QT,'A',ROUND(100*(NVL(A.CNT,0)/ A.CNT),2))),0) "A ALL %",
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(A.STATUS,'E',A.CNT)),0) AS "E TOTAL",
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(A.STATUS,'E',DECODE(A.QT,'A',A.CNT))),0) AS "E & A TOTAL"",
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(A.STATUS,'E',ROUND(100 * SUM((DECODE(A.QT,'A',A.CNT)) / SUM(A.CNT)),3))),0) "E & A %"
    FROM ALLIN A)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the query in a little more readable way using a common table expression;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    SUM(cnt) total,
    SUM(DECODE(qt,   'A', cnt, 0))      a_all,
    SUM(DECODE(type, 'E', cnt, 0))      e_total,
    SUM(DECODE(type||qt, 'EA', cnt, 0)) ea_total
  FROM allin
)
SELECT 
  total, a_all, ROUND(a_all/total*100, 2) a_percent,
  e_total, ea_total, ROUND(ea_total/e_total*100, 2) ea_percent
FROM cte;
```

This query generates the expected result and is a bit easier to read and debug. The `EA` part is assuming that qt and type are each one letter, so a concatenation of them matches EA. If that is not true, I recommend using a `CASE` instead, a'la;

```
SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'E' AND qt = 'A' THEN cnt ELSE 0 END) ea_total
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f01bb/1).